# boost_python with python 3.5 from anaconda - (few) undefined references

Tags: c++, python-3.x, boost, boost-python, embedding

boost: `1.60.0`
python: `3.5.0.1` (from anaconda)

sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <Python.h>

namespace py = boost::python;

int main()
{
    // Must be called before any boost::python functions
    Py_Initialize();
    // import the main module
    py::object main_module = py::import("__main__");
    // load the dictionary object out of the main module
    py::object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");
    // run simple code within the main namespace using the boost::python::exec 
    //  function
    py::exec("print ('Hello, world')", main_namespace);
    // any valid Python will execute
    py::exec("print ('Hello, world')[3:5]", main_namespace);
}
```

compiling as:
`g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test.o -I/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.1-0/include/python3.5m/ -L/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.1-0/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m -lpython3.5m -pthread -lutil -ldl -lboost_python3`

output:

```
//usr/local/lib/libboost_python3.so: undefined reference to `PyString_AsString'
//usr/local/lib/libboost_python3.so: undefined reference to `PyInt_Type'
//usr/local/lib/libboost_python3.so: undefined reference to `PyString_FromStringAndSize'
//usr/local/lib/libboost_python3.so: undefined reference to `PyString_FromString'
//usr/local/lib/libboost_python3.so: undefined reference to `PyString_FromFormat'
//usr/local/lib/libboost_python3.so: undefined reference to `PyInt_FromLong'
//usr/local/lib/libboost_python3.so: undefined reference to `PyInt_AsLong'
//usr/local/lib/libboost_python3.so: undefined reference to `PyString_Type'
```

Prior to this, I was getting other linker errors as well, I was linking with 2.7 version of python. I built `boost_python` with 3.5 version.

I understand that these functions are indeed not there for 3.5; don't know where they are being used.

On the contrary, pl find below:

```
:~/$ nm /usr/local/lib/libboost_python3.so |grep "PyString"
                 U PyString_AsString
                 U PyString_FromFormat
                 U PyString_FromString
                 U PyString_FromStringAndSize
                 U PyString_Type
:~/$ nm /usr/local/lib/libboost_python3.so |grep "PyInt"
                 U PyInt_AsLong
                 U PyInt_FromLong
                 U PyInt_Type
```

How can I simply 'Go Ahead'?

I in fact tried defining these functions inside C++ file, as I am fully aware that *I will not* be calling these, but it does not work. I know this was one hilarious way..., but to give you an idea, I wanna 'move on', I mentioned it.

Comment: Have tried it, gives same output

Answer (score 3):

I think your libboost_python3.so is for python 2.7 or python version before 3.1 since it refers to for example `PyString_AsString` that is not available in python 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4 or 3.5 (based on symbols found in libraries in debian packages).

```
nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0|grep PyString_AsString
0000000000112120 T PyString_AsString
0000000000111fd0 T PyString_AsStringAndSize
```

and python 3.4 (same for 3.5)

```
nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 |grep AsString
000000000017ea10 T PyByteArray_AsString
000000000017f680 T PyBytes_AsString
0000000000180cf0 T PyBytes_AsStringAndSize
```